# using browserify-css with grunt

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

I currently have grunt-browserify to build a few js files into a bundle. I'm trying to add css into the bundle via require('./style.css'). I've been researching some options to do this and found the browserify-css library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-css). However there is no grunt support so I'm not sure how to add this to my existing grunt settings.

It seems that I need to add browserify-css as a transform option. The grunt-browserify says that the transform option takes an array of tasks (see below). However, I don't think browserify-css can be written as a grunt task. What's the best practice in this situation?

```
    browserify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'dist/bundle.js': 'js/index.js'
            }
        },
        transform: ['coffeify']
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked the source code of browserify, and I found this solution:

```
browserify: {
    dist: {
      src: 'js/index.js',
      dest: 'dist/bundle.js'
    },
    options: {
        transform: [['browserify-css', { global: true }]]
    }
}
```

This works for me when I need to copy css files from node_modules folder. For make it work you only need to run:

```
npm install browserify browserify-css grunt-browserify --save-dev
```

and that's it!.

Comment: where do I set the general browserify-css configuration then? Will it be located in the gruntfile as well?

Comment: Yes, It should be on the same hierarchy of the rest of your grunt plugin configurations